# save() in php dom saves numbers at the end of the file

Tags: php, dom, save

The below code successfully saves the child div but also saves some numbers in the file at the end. I think its the bytes of data present, how do i get rid of the numbers it saves?

```
$file = '../userfolders/'.$email.'/'.$ongrassdb.'/'.$pagenameselected.'.php';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($file);
$ele = $doc->createElement('div', $textcon);
$ele ->setAttribute('id', $divname);
$ele ->setAttribute('style', 'background: '.$divbgcolor.'; color :'.$divfontcolor.' ;display : table-cell;');
$element = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
$element->appendChild($ele);
$doc->appendChild($element);
$myfile = fopen($file, "a+") or die('Unable to open file!');
$html = $doc->save($file);
fwrite($myfile,$html);
fclose($myfile);
```

I don't want to use `saveHTML` nor `saveHTMLFile` because it creates multiple instances of the divs and adds html tags to it.

Comment: Could you please provide the full file with all the variables and the file you're loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> $doc->load($file);
> ...
> $myfile = fopen($file, "a+") or die('Unable to open file!');
> $html = $doc->save($file);
> fwrite($myfile,$html);
> fclose($myfile);
> ```

The [`$doc->save()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) method saves the DOM tree to the file, and *returns* the number of bytes it wrote to the file. This number is stored in `$html` and is then append to the same file by `fwrite()`.

Just remove the `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the last two lines and it solved the issue

```
fwrite($myfile,$html);
fclose($myfile);
```